# Combining jQuery fade through list items for multiple divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

**The Problem:**

I currently have a script that's working, it basically looks through my list items with a class of 'sponsor-' and cycles through them at a set speed.

**So my html looks like:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="sponsor-1">This is sponsor one</li>
  <li class="sponsor-2">This is sponsor two</li>
  <li class="sponsor-3">This is sponsor three</li>
</ul>
```

**Working jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var divs = $('li[class^="sponsor-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() {

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(1000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
});
```

This is all good up to this point, but i need to know how i can add in extra list items into the same function. I have another list with a class's of 'fact-', which i want to cycle through as well. This is no doubt hideously wrong but this is what i tried.

**What i tried next (Not Working)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var sponsors = $('li[class^="sponsor-"]').hide(),

var facts = $('li[class^="fact-"]').hide(),

    i = 0;

(function cycle() {

    sponsors.eq(i).fadeIn(400),
     facts.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(1000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % sponsors.length;
    i = ++i % facts.length;

})();
});
```

This is not working, i just need some help to try add more in to the same function so i can target various other cycle lists.

**EDIT for Clarity**

I'm **NOT** looking for the cycle to first cycle sponsors then facts, i want the two cycles running simultaneously. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In the working jQuery code, just change:

`$('li[class^="sponsor-"]')`

to

`$('li[class^="sponsor-"], li[class^="fact-"]')`

To have the two lists separate, just duplicate the code (not the cleanest way, but its the quickest and easiest).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var sponsors = $('li[class^="sponsor-"]').hide(),

var facts = $('li[class^="fact-"]').hide(),

var facts_i = 0;
var sponsors_i = 0;

(function cycle() {


     sponsors.eq(sponsors_i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(1000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);


    sponsors_i = ++sponsors_i % sponsors.length;

})();

(function cycle2() {


     facts.eq(facts_i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(1000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle2);


    facts_i = ++facts_i % facts.length;

})();
});
```

Comment: If you do this, the jQuery will fade through a few sponsors then switch to fading a few facts. It effectively just treats the two lists as one object and does not run the two cycles simultaneously.

Comment: Edited answer, easiest way to accomplish it i think without restructuring/rewriting your code from sctrach (or better yet "plugin-ising" it).

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine if you change `divs` variable for example to this `var divs = $('li[class^="sponsor-"],li[class^="fact-"]')`

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6avD/).

**EDIT**
Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6avD/8/) to work with multiple lists. Now two cycles are working at the same time as the two completely separated lists.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sponsors = $('li[class^="sponsor-"]').hide(),
    facts = $('li[class^="fact-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

    function cycle(list,itemNbr) {
        list.eq(itemNbr).fadeIn(400).delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(400,function(){cycle(list,++itemNbr % list.length)});
    };

    cycle(sponsors,i);
    cycle(facts,i);    
});​
```

Comment: Sorry see my amended question at the bottom. I didn't explain it fully. I need the two cycles working at the same time as the two lists are completely separate from one another.